# Performing a join and groupBy on two dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe user_base and review_base. User_base has fields: elite, user_id, name, review_count, friends, fans.

Review_base has fields : review_id, user_id, cool, stars, business, useful, funny.

I want to find all users with their reviews lists and select some fields from each dataframe. This is my snippet code:

```
val reviews_per_user = user_base.join(review_base, "user_id")
.select(user_base("user_id"),user_base("elite"),user_base("review_count"),user_base("friends"),user_base("fans"),review_base("stars"),review_base("useful"),review_base("funny"),review_base("cool"))
.groupBy(user_base("user_id"))
```

Review_per_user is a RelationalGroupedDataset type but I want a Dataframe type to manipulate it with additional queries. What can I do about it?

Comment: sample input data and expected output shall help you get answers quickly

Answer (score 1):

```
val reviews_per_user = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT U.user_id, R.review_id FROM User_base U LEFT JOIN Review_base R ON U.user_id = R.user_id GROUP BY U.user_id, R.review_id)
```